# Adding Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-storage

I am trying to add to references `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient`. So there is a question: Is visual studio 2013 support `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient` reference?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install Azure SDK and add reference or create projects that can target various azure emulator or azure feature's within vs2013

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can install our latest Azure Storage Client Library through [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) and then start using the new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage namespace. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient namespace is no longer used since our 2.0 release.